Seeking Comprehensive GHS Hazard Database for Chemicals
I have been using PubChem as a source for GHS hazard information, but I have noticed that the database is incomplete for some chemicals. While PubChem is a great resource, I am looking for a more comprehensive database that provides Globally Harmonized System (GHS) hazard information for a wider range of chemicals.
If any of you are aware of a database that is more comprehensive than PubChem or have experience using one, I would greatly appreciate your guidance. Whether it is a publicly available resource, a subscription-based service, or even an internal database maintained by your organization, any leads or recommendations would be immensely helpful.
Also, if you have found alternative methods or resources to efficiently access GHS hazard information for chemicals, particularly for those not fully covered by PubChem, I would be interested to learn about your approaches as well.
